# Does closing a handle on a file release the associated memory in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, operating-system, virtual-machine

I am analyzing the performance of a product on Windows platform. Will closing the handle on that file using the CloseHandle() function flush the contents to the disk and remove it from the RAM?
Windows Platform : Windows Server 2008 R2 as a VM

Edit : I am analyzing a database product. And we are seeing sudden decrement in the RAM usage. I went through the MSDN for [CloseHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see a line which says "**After the last handle to an object is closed, the object is removed from the system.**" The word **system** here is not clear. We are already using FlushFileBuffers() to persist data before Closing the last Handle. 
Since database files can be huge, FlushFileBuffers() can result in a lot of  disk I/O. Can using the Windows Server as VM degrade the performance of disk I/O?

Comment: No, the writeback to disk is lazy.  Don't mess with it, using FlushFileBuffers() is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Closing a handle does not (reliably) flush unwritten data and it does not (generally) clear cached data. Doing that would mean that there would be effectively zero caching and lazy write back benefits.

I have observed Windows eagerly flushing and uncaching files but that is more an exception than the rule.

Comment: Is it also the same for last handle to a file?

Comment: Yes. Most cached files have zero handles open. Use RAMMap to look at the file cache contents.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling FlushFileBuffers() as this reduces the performance of the system and does not guarantee much regarding durability of your writes.

CloseHandle() applies to all types of handles, not just file handles. For example CreateEvent() returns a handle. The docs are referring to those types of "objects" as being "removed from the system". Files, unless they are marked as delete on close will remain in the file system after they are closed (obviously).